# How do you make python go through websites and get useful data?

Tags: python, python-requests

I wanted to get some data from a website, futbin.com, using python. The website has price data about every player in FIFA Ultimate Team. For example, if I want to check the price of Vidal, I would go to the link: https://www.futbin.com/20/player/19765/arturo-vidal and check his current price.

I tried to make a program that would do this for this specific player, but I was unable to do so since I am very new to using the "requests" library. So I looked online and found code for this exact program by darkyin87 https://github.com/darkyin87/futbin-scraper;

```html
import requests  
import json  

domain = 'https://www.futbin.com'  
version = 19  
page = 'playerPrices'  

player_ids = {  
  'Arturo Vidal': 181872,  
  'Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang': 188567,  
  'Robert Lewandowski': 188545,  
  'Jerome Boateng': 183907,  
  'Sergio Ramos': 155862,  
  'Antoine Griezmann': 194765,  
  'David Alaba': 197445,  
  'Paulo Dybala': 211110,  
  'Radja Nainggolan': 178518  
}

def fetch_prices():  
 ret_val = {}  
  for name, id in player_ids.iteritems():  
    url = "%s/%s/%s?player=%s" % (domain, version, page, id)  
    response = requests.get(url)  
    data = response.json()  
    ret_val[name] = data[str(id)]['prices']['ps']['LCPrice']  
  return ret_val  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
  prices = fetch_prices()  

fetch_prices
```

The code goes to a website different from the one I mentioned above and doesn't contain any graphical elements. It only has plain text and a bunch of other details about the player in plain text, which makes it easier for the program to read and manipulate: https://www.futbin.com/20/playerPrices/?player=181872.

I have no clue how the developer got access to this website because I can not find it by browsing through futbin.com.

So I guess I have 2 questions:

1. How would I go about achieving this task if I didn't have access to the plain text website, and
2. How do I find websites like these which have simple plain text which the code can manipulate.

Comment: Note that I modified my answer slightly as the result I initially gave did not seem to work with all players. The correct attribute to reference is `data-player-resource`

Comment: You're describing the difference between a webservice call and a webpage.  `https://www.futbin.com/20/playerPrices/?player=181872` is a webservice call.  You likely want access to the api definition so that you can request only the information you need without wasting bandwidth and effort scraping the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a little bit of googling, I found this similar question.

[Web-scraping futbin.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629888/web-scraping-futbin-com)

As you can see by the answer there, Selçuk suggests that they are making http requests for the chart data. Following that logic, you can inspect your network tab in developer tools and monitor the requests.

If we monitor the requests and look for ones that result in price data, we get the following request.

`https://www.futbin.com/20/playerPrices?player=181872`

Note that the ID is not the same as the Player ID in the link you mentioned (19765). To get this unique ID, we have to do some additional work.

1. Load the original page you linked.
2. Locate the new unique ID within the page.
3. Make the request to the link above using the new unique ID.
4. The result is a JSON that you can figure out how to parse for your needs.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

player_id = 19765 #Arturo Vidal

# Request the main page to get info about the player
r = requests.get("https://www.futbin.com/20/player/" + str(player_id)).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
page_info = soup.find(id='page-info')
request_id = page_info['data-player-resource'] #Get the ID to make the second request

# Request to get a JSON of price data for player 19765 with internal id request_id
r = requests.get("https://www.futbin.com/20/playerPrices?player=" + request_id).content
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This URL, the GitHub code you got uses, is for the websites back-end, it's the API that provides the data for the front-end. So, when you navigate to player page the front-end makes a request to the back-end and gets the data it's supposed to render.

You can check what the front-end is calling if you open your browser developer tools and go the network tab before navigating to the page.